# Remove tabs on product page

Tags: product, tabs

I need all product information like in default magento theme but without tabs. 
And i need to order of product details like this:
first: additional information
below it a separator line or box and:
second: description
below it a line and:
Reviews
I use magento 1.9.1.0 with rwd theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog\product\view.phtml`

Edit above file & comment below lines of code, It will remove your tabs from the product view page.

```
    <div class="product-collateral toggle-content tabs">
            <?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')):?>
                <dl id="collateral-tabs" class="collateral-tabs">
                    <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $alias => $html):?>
                        <dt class="tab"><span><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getChildData($alias, 'title')) ?></span></dt>
                        <dd class="tab-container">
                            <div class="tab-content"><?php echo $html ?></div>
                        </dd>
                    <?php endforeach;?>
                </dl>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: thank you Adeel; but this code disable all product information and i need product information like in magento theme with full description, additional information and Reviews products, but without tabs.

Comment: Remove the tab classes form the above code & in css do following .product-collateral > dl > dd {display:block !important;} .product-collateral > dl > dt {display:block !important;}

Comment: Thank you, Its work :) and how can i change the order of product information? like this: first "ADDITIONAL INFORMATION" below it "DESCRIPTION" and below it "Reviews"

Comment: You can control order from catalog.xml for description & additional information  & review.xml for review

Check   <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>  in both file

Answer (score 0):

you can display product information to get with help of `$this->getChildGroup` function

```
<?php foreach ($this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml') as $alias => $html):?>
        <div class="box-collateral <?php echo "box-{$alias}"?> <?php if($alias == "additional") { echo "detail-box alignleft"; } else { echo "detail-box alignright"; }?>">
            <?php if ($title = $this->getChildData($alias, 'title')):?>
            <h2><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?></h2>
            <?php endif;?>
            <?php echo $html; ?>
        </div>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

above will display information from

```
  <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description" as="description" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
                    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                </block>
               <block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml">
                    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                </block>
```

both blocks.

Comment: @user24183, its really unfair that you accepted answer before and now change your mind. :(

Comment: This is my first post here and i am unfamiliar with the system of this site. I accept Adeel's answer before your answer and with respect to your request, tried to accept both, but i see Adeel's answer unchecked! Adeel have a complete answer and answered before you.

Comment: not before me mister.After see my answer he is added some comment you can see time.But no worries.i will be careful to your post second time